# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cake\Console\CommandRunner' not found

Tags: cakephp, xampp, fedora-25

Operating system: Fedora 25,
cakePHP version 3,
PHP version 7

How can i fix this class not found issue, the error is showing when trying to run bin/cake bake command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you might have a new application skeleton with an older CakePHP. Try updating your CakePHP version to the latest 3.5

Comment: Is there any command to update cakephp in ubuntu? Please help me to resolve this issue...

Comment: No there is not. The ubuntu package is quite old and does not get updated. You should switch to installing Cake with composer instead of apt-get.